# Is it possible to kill the 2nd Arsenal Bird before its shield is brought down permanently?

Tags: ace-combat-7-skies-unknown

In the penultimate mission of Ace Combat 7, "Lighthouse", the objective of the latter part of the mission is to destroy the Arsenal Bird, a large flying fortress with an impenetrable shield. In the first phase of this fight, the shield repeatedly turns on and off, giving you several brief windows of time to deal damage while the shield is down. Finally, a story event occurs that results in the shield being permanently deactivated, and dealing damage becomes much easier after this point. However, I've always wondered whether it's possible to "sequence break" the mission by dealing enough damage to kill the Arsenal Bird *before* the story event takes place. Does anyone know if this is possible? If not, is it because the mission is specifically scripted to prevent early destruction of the Arsenal Bird, or is it simply because no player-accessible aircraft can deal damage quickly enough to destroy the Arsenal Bird in those small windows of vulnerability?